# Why is it important to distinguish between coordinates and coordinate functions?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

In a [book](https://books.google.cz/books/about/Differential_Geometry_and_the_Calculus_o.html?id=T8A9H2yfP-YC&redir_esc=y/%22book%22) by Robert Hermann, chapter 4, the author tries to specialize the general theory of differentiable manifolds to plain $\mathbb{R}^n,$ and he distinguishes between $n-$tuples $(x_j),$ $1\leq j \leq n,$ which he calls *points* and $x_j$ without parentheses, which are the real-valued functions assigning to $(x_j)$ the $j$th **coordinate** of $(x_j).$ Then he makes the remark that the reader should note that much of the notational confusion in undergraduate differential calculus is caused by not making this distinction. My questions are:

1) If the points $(x_j)$ are $n-$tuples, is it meant that the $j$th coordinate that the author is referring to in the definition of $x_j$ above is nothing more than the $j$th slot in the ordered $n-$tuple? Or is he in fact presupposing a vector space structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the coordinate $x_j$ is really a coordinate of a vector $(x_j)$ with respect to (canonical) basis? And is this distinction important at all?

2) What are some good examples illustrating the point that not making the distinction between coordinates and coordinate functions can lead to confusion?

Comment: A coordinate is the value of the projection of the point by the projection $\pi_j:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ to the $j$-th factor. So, for (1) yes, seeing $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space the coordinate is the coordinate in the standard basis.

Comment: Coordinate function would be projection $\pi_j$. The thing is that abusing notation often times people don't call them with a different name and call them $x_j$. But in that case you should understand that $x_j$ is referring to the function $x_j:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ that sends a point $p$  to its $j$-th coordinate.

Comment: More context, such as exact quotes, would help.

Comment: Suppose you use other coordinate functions, say $a,b:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $a(x,y)=x+y^2$ and $b(x,y)=y$. Then the coordinates of $(1,2)$ in that coordinate system are $(a(1,2),b(1,2))=(5,2)$.

Comment: @Acccumulation: the precise context is given here https://books.google.cz/books?id=T8A9H2yfP-YC&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=notational+confusion+in+calculus&source=bl&ots=V7mWiqmnHC&sig=FvGRI8HrH_dozrH9OVxDdIzzHIk&hl=cs&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPsJXOpfvZAhWmJZoKHfcbCEcQ6AEIQTAD#v=onepage&q=notational%20confusion%20in%20calculus&f=false

Comment: @SphericalTriangle: so when you write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$ and you do mean the standard partial derivative of a function on $R^n,$ you are using coordinates or coordinate functions?

Comment: Yes, that $x_j$ appearing in $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$ is the coordinate function.

Comment: Using [the definition that would allow me to talk the less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_via_cotangent_spaces), the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ is just the dual basis of the basis in the cotangent space formed by the images of the functions $x_j$ in there.

Comment: And well, the alternative in your questions is what? Partial derivative with respect to a coordinate? A coordinate is a number. You don't take partial derivatives with respect to a number.

Comment: Now, bear in mind that speaking fast, and even written in books and papers you will see people calling 'coordinates' and 'coordinate' to the coordinate functions. Human language is context dependent. You will have to infer what is the actual meaning intended. Your book in emphasizing the difference to prepare you for what is coming next: Changing coordinates. I mean, changing systems of coordinate functions.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle: well, to be pedantic, partial derivatives are traditionally described as taken with respect to (independent) "variables". However, due to implicit function theorem, the term is somewhat ill-defined. I had some hopes that manifold theory is devised to remedy this, but still I feel I miss something important. I believe the devil is somehow hidden in viewing $R^n$ simultaneously as a set of $n-$tuples (with some metric) and as a vector space.

Comment: No. That description of partial derivatives wouldn't be pedantic, it would be ambiguous. What is independent? What is a variable? The precise way is what I linked (and other equivalent ways): Let $I$ be the smooth functions vanishing at the origin. Let $I^2$ the sums of products of elements of $I$. Then $I/I^2$ is a finite dimensional space over $\mathbb{R}$ called the co-tangent space. A system of coordinate functions is a set of functions $x_1,...,x_n\in I$ such that their images in $I/I^2$ are linearly independent. Therefore, their images form a basis. The dual space of $I/I^2$ is the ...

Comment: ... tangent space. Given a basis of a space one has an associated basis of the dual space. The dual of the basis $x_1,...,x_n$ is called $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1},...,\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74826/discussion-between-jorge-squared-and-sphericaltriangle).

Comment: @SphericalTriangle so what is the partial derivative of f(x,y)=x+y w.r.t x at  (1,1).(assuming coordinate function that u had defined above).